# mongodb unable establish remote cursors

Tags: mongodb

Anybody seen this messages before in mongodb sharded cluster 4.0.16 mongos  during balancing:

```
   2021-10-24T13:26:03.723+0200 I QUERY    [conn636] Unable to establish remote cursors - {error: StaleConfig{ ns: "prod.assests", vReceived: Timestamp(1841827, 4), vReceivedEpoch: ObjectId('584af7e7cec9edde8118d5ac'), vWanted: Timestamp(1841826, 1), vWantedEpoch: ObjectId('584af7e7cec9edde8118d5ac') }: version mismatch detected for prod.assests, numActiveRemotes: 0}
   2021-10-24T13:26:03.723+0200 I QUERY    [conn768] Unable to establish remote cursors - {error: StaleConfig{ ns: "prod.assests", vReceived: Timestamp(1841827, 4), vReceivedEpoch: ObjectId('584af7e7cec9edde8118d5ac'), vWanted: Timestamp(1841826, 1), vWantedEpoch: ObjectId('584af7e7cec9edde8118d5ac') }: version mismatch detected for prod.assests, numActiveRemotes: 0}
   2021-10-24T13:26:03.723+0200 I QUERY    [conn507] Unable to establish remote cursors - {error: StaleConfig{ ns: "prod.assests", vReceived: Timestamp(1841827, 4), vReceivedEpoch: ObjectId('584af7e7cec9edde8118d5ac'), vWanted: Timestamp(1841826, 1), vWantedEpoch: ObjectId('584af7e7cec9edde8118d5ac') }: version mismatch detected for prod.assests, numActiveRemotes: 4}
```

This messages appear only during balancing in a 5x shards (1TB on ssd each) cluster in all mongoses...
Also messages appear only during the mentioned collection balancing , other collections balance with no such messages in same cluster...

The questions:

1.Any advice will be highly appreciated on why this messages appear?

2.What is the meaning of this message, do I need to worry about ?

3. Is there possible fix?

Balancing seems working correctly ...

Customers not complaining , queries to cluster working correctly ...

RangeDeleter working correctly ....

There is no  network or storage resources issues  ...

The load is minimal during the time of balancing ...

Comment: try suggestions from here https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/shard-version-not-ok-version-mismatch-detected-for/7150 if no, then create a ticket

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/8be03e014addf0252d718ed329ab8d5235e0fdec/src/mongo/db/s/collection_sharding_runtime.cpp#L365-L369.  are you taking writes during rebalancing?  I think this occurs when the shard has taken a write and invalidates the shard version it just sent the balance target.  The target then needs to reach out and get the updated one.  I believe this is the intended way for it to operate (shard checksums if it allows writes during the balance).  Ideally, you'd use these logs to understand if you should defer writes until after the balance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This message is expected behaviour during balancing when there is read request for documents already migrated to other shard.
2. The meaning is that the mongos is not able to establish remote cursor to the old shard since the config is reported stale and data is moved to the new shard.
3. No fix is necessary this is informative message only.

Comment: could you please reference any documentation regarding the 3rd point "No fix is necessary this is informative message only."? Also, does this mean Mongos was able to establish a remote cursor to the right shard later and serve the query just fine?